# Convert VBA to Javascript (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I would like to convert my VBA to something I can use for Google Apps Script.

```
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'

'
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B15").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Rows("15:15").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("B2").Select
End Sub
```

And I ended up with this:

```
function Macro5(){

Range("B2").Select;
Selection.Copy;
Range("B15").Select;
Selection.Paste;
=xlPasteValues, Operation;
=xlNone, SkipBlanks;
=False, Transpose;
=False;
Application.CutCopyMode = False;
Rows("15:15").Select;
Selection.Insert Shift;
=xlDown, CopyOrigin;
=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove;
Range("B2").Select;
}
```

But it didn't work out. Anyone here who knows how to make this work?

Function: It needs to select B2 and copy the cell and paste it on B15, create a row above it, click on Esc and select B2 again. I want this integrated in a button.

Comment: Putting curly braces round a VBA function doesn't make it JavaScript.... I suggest you go and actually look at how to write some basic JavaScript, research the Google Sheets API and then make a real attempt and converting the code. There's more than likely even examples for this very thing in the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer that I knew myself. The thing is that I really need to get this to work, and I was hoping I would find a better answer here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Have you actually tried to write any JavaScript for this?

Comment: Not exactly javascript, I tried to convert the sub code to a code that is available to Google Apps Script. I am not here to learn how to work with javascript, I am asking for help for someone who knows how to make this work, or has another way around to use a macro thing like on google spreadsheets

Answer (score 1):

Although in this network I do not agree to do this kind of request, today I want to give you my help by publishing these 4 lines of code.
Anyway, I strongly advise you not to make any other requests like this in this network.

Thank you for your kindly cooperation.

```
function Macro5() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var last = sheet.getLastColumn();
  sheet.getRange(2,2).copyTo(sheet.getRange(15, 2));
  sheet.insertRowAfter(15);

  var data = sheet.getRange(15,1, 1, last).getValues();
  var dest = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) { dest.push(data[i]); }

  if (dest.length > 0 ) { sheet.getRange(16,1,1,last).setValues(dest); } 

  sheet.getRange(2, 2).activate();
}
```